# npm install + extra command

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gruntjs

Is it possible to append to a task to "npm install". I have a node project in which I'm using Grunt as task runner. To fully install the project, one of course needs to get the dependencies by running "npm install". After this it is still not fully setup however, and one needs to also run a command via grunt. Now I'd like all required installation tasks to be done with a single command.

Is it possible to append a task to run to "npm install", so it becomes "npm install ; grunt mytask" when someone runs "npm install"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your package.json file can contain a "scripts" property: https://npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-scripts.html

The "postinstall" script sounds like it would fit your needs.

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts

Answer (score 1):

I re-read your post, and I think I understood it wrong the first time.

I believe what you are looking for is here: https://npmjs.org/doc/scripts.html

Hth, 
Aaron